# Get Request to a spark server with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, post, get, endpoint

So I'm working on this project where I need to create an Admin Console that will show the list of users, accounts, etc. 
Most of the work is already done, and my teammate has made a Spark Server which basically served up all of our data and gave me an endpoint, which is a JSON file for me to access. The problem is I'm new to angular and I'm not sure how to make GET and Post requests using AngularJS. I'm just trying to view the JSON file and post to it(the endpoint) as well, I'm not too sure how to write it now. So any help is appreciated, I've looked at many articles and I've tested a lot I just haven't been able to access what I needed. The endpoint supplied to me was like this:

http://54.87.197.206:8080/SparkServer/admin/api/v1/listOf/users:

when you click on the link it looks like this

```
[
  {
    "password": "password",
    "phoneNumber": "5712474645",
    "name": "Daniel",
    "id": "1994661273",
    "email": "dkrinke@gmu.edu",
    "username": "dkrinke"
  },
  {
    "password": "password",
    "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
    "name": "Brad",
    "id": "1466124435",
    "email": "bwebber@gmu.edu",
    "username": "bWebber"
  }
]
```

and I've made a simple HTML file with some angular in it the way that I think to approach the problem.

[File I made to try and access the endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2W0d.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The common, idiomatic, and maintainable approach is to encapsulate the data access logic into a dedicated AngularJS service. The service itself will use the frameworks built in HTTP client service which is optimized with JSON friendly default behavior.

In order to leverage the aforementioned AngularJS HTTP client service, we will actually create an injectable service factory that will receive the HTTP client as a parameter and return our service. The service itself will just be a simple object with that exposes a function to get the users from the API endpoint.

Here is what our service factory will look like

```
(function () {

  userService.$inject = ['$http']; // tell AngularJS to inject HTTP service as first param
  function userService($http) {
    var apiUrl = 'http://54.87.197.206:8080/SparkServer/admin/api/v1/listOf/users';

    var service = {
      getUsers: function() {
        return $http.get(apiUrl)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
          });
      },
      createUser: function(user) {
        return $http.post(apiUrl, user)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
          });
      }
    };

    return service;
  }
```

Now that we have created our service factory and used the `$inject` property to tell AngularJS to inject its `$http` service, we simply need to register it.

```
  angular.module('app') // assumes module is already defined by other code
    .factory('userService', userService);

}());
```

Now we can inject our `userService` into a controller, directive, or into another service.

For example, we may have a `UsersController` that needs to access the service (the object returned by the factory).

Here is what such a controller might look like

```
(function () {

  UsersController.$inject = ['userService']; // inject the service we registered above
  function UsersController(userService) {
    var that = this;
    this.users = []; // initialize to empty array while we wait for data to load

    userService.getUsers()
      .then(function (users) {
        that.users = users;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });

    this.newUser = {};

    this.createUser = function (user) {
      return userService.createUser(that.newUser)
        .then(function (user) {
          that.users.push(user);
          that.newUser = {};
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    };
  }
}());
```

**create-user.html**

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.createUser()">
  name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.newUser.name" name="name" />
  password:
  <input type="password" ng-model="$ctrl.newUser.password" name="password" />
  confirm password:
  <input type="password" ng-model="$ctrl.newUser.confirmPassword" name="confirm-password" />

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**create-user.js**

```
(function () {

  var createUser = {
    templateUrl: './create-user.html',
    controller: 'UsersController'
  };

  angular.module('app')
    .component('createUser', createUser);

}());
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aluan! Quick follow up though, so if I want to create an HTML view of that data I just use ng-repeat in my html file, something like user.username inside the ng-repeat, right?

Comment: Oh also what if I needed to make a post request, as in I need to add a new user with all the elements?

Comment: Yes, use ng-repeat to enumerate users in your html.

Comment: I added stub code for creating a user, you will need to adjust it slightly based on how the rest of your app is wired up.

Comment: Hmm I'm alittle confused on how to write the service factory. So I initialized the app in a separate js file like this:
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
then in a seperate file called theFactory.js put in the first code stub you gave me, is that all i do? or do i need to do something like 
angular.module('app').factory(*insert your stub code here*);


sorry for so many questions, I'm still really new to most angularjs syntax

Comment: I've already done most of the implementation, you wire it up in your app. Consult AngularJS documentation. I do not have time right now.

Comment: You could put it all in the same file if that helps you but you have right idea.

Comment: I believe there's an error in the UsersController, in this.createUser = function(user), when I run everything theres an unexpected token error in the .THEN function. So I added function(user), I'm not sure if thats what is supposed to be there though

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was missing the function keyword and `(` I also added a missing `return` to the example